# Not able to go to FragmentOne from MainAcvitivty

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Main Activity:

```
package piestudio.opinion;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.toi) {
            FragmentOne FragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_frame, FragmentOne, "Times of India")
                    .commit();
            drawer.closeDrawer(navigationView);
        } else if (id == R.id.thehindu) {
        } else if (id == R.id.support) {
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

FragmentOne.java:

```
package piestudio.opinion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;

/**
 * Created by jene on 7/4/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    Activity MainActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        MainActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

## What do I want to do with my app?

I have a navigation drawer in my app with three options:

1. Times of India
2. The Hindu
3. Support

Now I want to go to `FragmentOne` when the user clicks on Times of India in the navigation drawer.

## Problem with my code

The above code is working fine, but doesn't function correctly - when I click Times of India, nothing happens.

If you want to see the nav drawer for a better idea, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLWWc.png).

Logcat:

```
07-08 11:56:52.301 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.305 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.305 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.305 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.321 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.325 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.325 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.325 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionManager', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.329 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.353 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.357 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:56:52.357 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.MainActivity.access$super
07-08 11:57:01.429 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.FragmentOne.access$super
07-08 11:57:01.429 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.FragmentOne.access$super
07-08 11:57:01.429 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.FragmentOne.access$super
07-08 11:57:01.429 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.FragmentOne.access$super
07-08 11:57:01.429 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.FragmentOne.access$super
07-08 11:57:01.429 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.FragmentOne.access$super
07-08 11:57:01.449 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.FragmentOne.access$super
07-08 11:57:01.453 1281-1281/piestudio.opinion E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method piestudio.opinion.FragmentOne.access$super
```

Layout to Main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app bar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="piestudio.opinion.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorDark"

        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I recommend not naming your objects exactly the same as your classes: `FragmentOne FragmentOne = new FragmentOne();` <- this is pretty confusing.

Comment: @CodeConfident i did not get it please explain :) . rest of the code is fine ?

Comment: I'm just suggesting naming your Fragment object differently to your class. `FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();` and `.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentOne, "Times of India")`. I suggest you post your layout xml for the Activity too.

Comment: @CodeConfident done have a look

Comment: ...and the layout that's included from app_bar_main ^^Did you fix the object naming?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten too much of your project files, you do not allow us to understand the problem . The approach that I can recommend is the one that I usually follow:

DrawerActivity: (mainActivity)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

// add compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView mNavigationView;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    });
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

    // Set the listener 
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            // when you click an option, call showFragment() method
            showFragment(menuItem);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mNavigationView);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

//  method that swaps fragments
public void showFragment(final MenuItem menuItem) {
    final int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
    final Fragment nextFragment;
    switch (itemId) {

        // open YoutFragment
        case R.id.timesOfIndia:
            nextFragment = new YourFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.anchor_point, nextFragment)
                    .commit();
            break;
        case R.id.theHindu:
            nextFragment = new YourFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.anchor_point, nextFragment)
                    .commit();
            break;
    }
} 
}
```

activity_drawer.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/anchor_point"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

remember to add a "menu" folder with this menu.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<item
    android:id="@+id/timesOfIndia"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Times of India"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>



<item
    android:id="@+id/theHindu"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="The Hindu"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
 </menu>
```

EDIT ( After you provide the Fragment code...):

I tested the code I provided you , it works . You also have problems because you do not do the inflate of the fragment layout.
Your fragment must be like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class YourFragment extends Fragment {


public YourFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your, container, false);
}

}
```

Comment: no , bro your code is not working too :( there is no error yet i am not able to move from one Activity to fragment

Comment: Also you do not do the inflate of the fragment layout, i've update answer with the fragment code

Comment: your code is showing this when i click on times on india option it shows the  text "helloworld!your fragment is active" whereas when i click on times of india option it should show "your fragment is active" only as hello world is a text of main activity and fragment is active is a text of FragmentOne

[link](https://i.imgsafe.org/0a18bb784f.png)  visit this link for proper understanding